# How to get all unchecked radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok, so I've got a jQuery code which constructs my radio inputs from XML data, like this:

```
var items = xml.children('item');
if (items.length > 0)
{
    var ul = $('<ul/>',{
        class: 'priceList'
    });
    items.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var li = $('<li/>');
        var img = $('<img/>',{
            src: 'products/' + $this.children('image').text(),
        });
        var input = $('<input/>',{
            type: 'radio',
            id: $this.children('id').text(),
            name: 'products'
        });
        var span = $('<span/>',{
            text: $this.children('price').text() + ' USD'
        });
        var label = $('<label/>',{
            for: $this.children('id').text()
        });
        label.append(img);
        label.append("</br>");
        label.append(span);
        li.append(input);
        li.append(label);
        ul.hide().append(li).fadeIn('slow');
    });
    return ul;
}
return null;
```

Now I need a nice way to find all unchecked radio labels and do something with them, e.g. fade them out or change a css property. Since the XML list consists of nearly 40 items, writing an if-else construction is a no-go. Need a good solution. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** See my answer below.

Comment: Just curious.  Can you make the style for the unchecked bottons the default and only restyle the checked one?  Seems it would be much easier and more efficient if you can.

Comment: of course I can. But it wouldn't get me the result I need. the viewer needs to see all elements unaltered before he checks one of them.

Comment: Gotcha.  Gonna have to mull on this.  Someone will probably happen along with a good solution quickly in any case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found it myself. None of the above answers worked for me, which is strange, because most of them should be totally legit.

What I found to be working is actually

```
$('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)')
```

And in my case I needed

```
$('li input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label')
```

And the whole code is:

```
//we'll need m for detecting a click outside of element with our radio buttons...
var m = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", url: 'xml.xml', dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(data){
            var xml = $(data);
            $('#windowList').append( ItemToUl(xml.children()) );
        }
    });
    $('.calc').hover(function(){ 
        m=true; 
    }, function(){ 
        m=false; 
    });
    $("body").mousedown(function(){ 
        if(! m) { 
            //...and unchecking a checked radio. I heard that .attr() was deprecated but couldn't get .prop() to work
            $('li input[type="radio"]:checked').attr('checked', false);
            $('li input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label').fadeTo('slow', 1);
        }
    });
    $("li input").live("change", function(){
        $('li input[type="radio"]:checked + label').fadeTo('slow', 1);
        $('li input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label').fadeTo('slow', 0.45);
    }); 
});

//constructing function, etc...
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this (also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNAx5/)):

```
$('input').not(':checked')
```

Answer (score 2):

i think this sould work

```
$("input:!checked");
```

You may want to put a class selector in there as well.

Then do an `.each` to do something with the elements

Comment: Are you sure this is valid JQuery?  I'm messing around with it a little and can't get it to work.  But it's late and I'm tired :)

Comment: this does not work for me. I believe you should use "input:not(:checked)"  just like in the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('unchecked');
    // or
    $(this).slideUp('slow');
});
```

Obviously the element you use is up to you but the :unchecked selector is what you're after.