# Javascript method to get the value of unselected checkboxes html page

Tags: javascript, web-services, checkbox

I have a form where there are more checkboxes, I would like to know if there is a script to get the value of the checkboxes not selected and put the value on array in java or something else when the confirmation button is pressed

I don't know how to use jquery

```html
<table class="scroll">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome Servizio</th>
      <th>Descrizione</th>
      <th>Autorizza</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>searchZona</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value=2#1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>showUserServicesPanel</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value=2#2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>searchStructureAgent</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value=2#3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>searchCostruttore</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value=2#4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>getStructureAgent</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value=2#5></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>getSottoGruppo</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value=2#6></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: can you provide a sample code of what you have done

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: @TiisetsoTjabane i update

Comment: @Minimum effort.. my question is different then the other questions... i want to get the value of checkbox not selected

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592803/how-to-get-all-unchecked-radio-buttons

Comment: Can i use jquery with html page?

Comment: Sure - it will make it a bit easier.

Comment: @mplungjan but with jquery can i return to java an array with values of checkboxes not selected?

Comment: `var notSelArr = $('input:checkbox:not(":checked")').map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get()`

Comment: can you make me an example on jsfiddle? I'm new on programming with jquery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/sukwfbex/

Comment: ok thanks!.. i can change the function when form submit?

Answer (score 0):

Using a simplified version of your code you can achieve this by using:

`document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)')`

This will give you a HTML collection of your input elements which have NOT been checked.

You can then use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (optional) to convert your array of elements to an array of values from each element.

See working example below (minified version):

get all the checkbox items when you click your button and then

```js
const createArray = _ => {
  let foods = [...document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)')];
  foods = foods.map(({value:v}) => v);
  console.log(foods);
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="apple" />
<input type="checkbox" value="carrot" />
<input type="checkbox" value="tomato" />
<input type="checkbox" value="potato" />
<br />
<button onclick="createArray()">Create array</button>
```

Comment: well but I use web services.. In my html page which contains checkboxes when i press button confirmed i want to pass the value of checkboxes selected and not selected.. Now I can't get unchecked checkbox values

Comment: this is the call of the service which control checkboxes

Comment: `@Path("UpdateUserServices")
 @POST
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
 public String UpdateUserServices2(@FormParam("check") List<String> check, @FormParam("notSelArr")List<String> notsel)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that :

```js
const formEl = document.getElementById('myForm');
formEl.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {

  const inputs = formEl.getElementsByTagName('input');
  const uncheckedCheckboxesValue = []
  for(let i = 0, iEnd = inputs.length; i < iEnd; i++) {
    const input = inputs[i];
    
    if(input.getAttribute('type') === 'checkbox' && !input.checked) {
      uncheckedCheckboxesValue.push(input.value);
    }
  }
  
  if(uncheckedCheckboxesValue.length > 0) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent send the form
      console.log(uncheckedCheckboxesValue);
  }

}, false);;
```

```css
#myForm label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">

<label>A: <input type="checkbox" value="Aval" /></label>
<label>B: <input type="checkbox" value="Bval" /><br /></label>
<label>C: <input type="checkbox" value="Cval" /><br /></label>
<label>D: <input type="checkbox" value="Dval" /><br /></label>
<label>E: <input type="checkbox" value="Eval" /><br /></label>

<input type="submit" id="myFormSubmit" />

</form>
```